# Можно ли из Fragment вызвать finish() для Activity?

Tags: android, activity

Можно ли из `Fragment` вызвать `finish()` для `Activity`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да можно

```
getActvity().finish()
```

Comment: И всё?!! А я тут мудрю...Спасибо!